# Загрузка нового apk приложения - ошибка номера версии

Tags: android, google-play

Здравствуйте! При загрузке новой версии приложения в Google Play возникает ошибка такого вида:
APK-файл с кодом версии 1 уже существует. Используйте другой код.
Вопрос заключается в том, где и как можно заменить этот самый код?

Answer (score 17):

### **Update**

в `build.gradle(Module: app)`

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode 2 //для Google Play
        versionName "1.1" //для пользователей
    }
}
```

---

в `manifest` Вашего проекта

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="......"
          android:versionCode="26"
          android:versionName="3.1.6">
```

Comment: т,е чтобы просто заменить код вместо xml version="1.0" ставим xml version="2.0" после чего создаем apk ?

Comment: не-не, я указал часть где меняется версия кода.

Answer (score 8):

Чтобы Google Play принял новую версию приложения, нужно повысить версию кода `android:versionCode`. Если ранее `android:versionCode="1"`, то в новой версии он должен быть на 1 больше - `android:versionCode="2"`.

Если Вы пишете приложения в среде разработки Android Studio С применением Gradle системы сборки, то версию кода нужно будет повышать в файле `build.gradle` уровня приложения, то есть того, что лежит в папке `/app`. Внутри этого файла Вы легко найдете строчку `versionCode`.

`versionName` - Ваша собственная версия приложения, ее можно показывать пользователям. Она может быть двойная, тройная, с буквами.

На Википедии подробнее об этом - [Нумерация версий программного обеспечения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

После этого нужно собрать `*.apk` через `Build-Generate signed APK...`.

Успехов!

Comment: а строку  versionName "1.0" нужно заменять на строку  versionName "2.0"?

Comment: @Вячеслав, не обязательно та. Вы можете написать 1.1. Или 1.0.1. `versionName` - это для себя и пользователей. Как хотите, так и пишете.

Comment: @Вячеслав, я обновил свой ответ. Извините, пожалуйста, первый раз не ту ссылку прикрепил((( Сейчас верная. В статье описан ответ на Ваш вопрос о `versionName`.

Answer (score 3):

Если работаете в Android Studio, то зайдите в структуру проекта - кнопка на панели инструментов или *File / Project Structure...* или сочетание клавиш *Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S*.

Заходите в настройки вашего приложения *Modules / app*, вкладка *Flavors*. Там меняете код версии (+ 1) и название версии (при необходимости). Для публикации обновления в Google Play достаточно изменить только код версии.