# Ошибка версии приложения; Error "application_version"

Tags: java, android

При запуске выскакивают ошибки:

```
C:\AndroidProjects\***\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-support\debug\dependencies\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(2) resource string/common_application_version (*** :string/common_application_version) not found.
Error:failed processing manifest.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Это мой манифест:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="***"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="@string/common_application_version">
```

Это манифест который создается при сборке gradle:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="ru.SoftMasters.ILSARMobileMonitor"
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="@string/common_application_version"
  split="lib_dependencies_apk">
</manifest>
```

Это string на который и ругается студия:

```
<string name="common_application_version">1.11.0</string>
```

Пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с подобной ошибкой подскажите как вы это исправляли... 
Заранее спасибо всем за участие!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510874/205563